# What items are announced to chat when bought?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have noticed that some items get announced to chat when purchased, what items gets anounced and what makes them so special?
[image: purchased item in chat]

Comment: @GGClassic-Jona52 after some self testing one of the "good answers" is definitely wrong, so i would like some citation/source.

Comment: Oh ok. I dont think there is a definite list of every single item since it is a little new.  But maybe someone will buy all the items and make one ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Items that provide "team support".

- Wards
- Oracle's Extract/Elixir
- Items that grant an [aura](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aura) to allies or a [debuff](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aura) to nearby enemies

This is so that (1) people know that you are spending money for the team and (2) so that your allies don't double up on an aura item accidentally.

Comment: Remember that most auras can be purchased by 2 teammates to maximize their effect!

Comment: @Toast It only doubles up the aura on the two players who have the aura item. However, both players will be a source of the aura for allies. Depending on how much the two teammates stay together, this may/may not be desirable.

Comment: Do you have a citation/source for this information?

Comment: @blem The [patch notes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1870030) are a little vague. They do specify wards and aura items, though. As for "top-tier" items, I don't know of any others it lists. I know it at least does not list some "selfish" items, like Infinity Edge, from play experience. It doesn't look like anyone has compiled a complete list anywhere. I would look to see if the "counter" items are announced, like Quicksilver Sash and Executioner's Calling.

Comment: It appears there's a different set of items for Spectator mode, and ingame. Ingame it appears only aura items, wards, oracle's Elixer, and Executioner's Calling, while it spectator mode, it appears almost every tier 2 items (Items made from 2 other items) and tier 3 items are announced.

Answer (score 2):

Support items that help your team or debuff the enemy team. These include (off the top of my head):

1. Sight Wards/vision wards
2. Oracle's Elixir
3. Aegis of the Legion
4. Frozen Heart
5. Shurelya's Reverie
6. Locket of the Iron Solari
7. Zeke's Herald
8. Will of the Ancients

Answer (score 2):

From the official patch notes:

> Important items purchased by your team will now be called out in chat
>   (Aura items,  Sight and  Vision Wards, top tier items, etc)

Wards, Aura Items, and Legendary items all show up in chat.

Comment: League of legends wiki classifies [Banshee's Veil](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Banshee%27s_Veil) as a [Legendary item](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_item) but it does not show up in chat when bought.

Answer (score 0):

:) Executioner's calling as well. Because it's essentially a built-in ignite, so enemy healers/regenerators are crippled. Lets your team know to focus the one you bast with the activation.

Answer (score -1):

People viewing the match in Spectator mode sees all items that are bought such as Wits End in the chat.